# How to correctly setup pip install when switching from python 2.6 to 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I have an AWS ubuntu instance (its an EMR AMI 2.4.7, actually) with the default python being 2.6.
I want to use python2.7.5.

Python 2.7.5 is already installed on the machine and is just not the default

so I just change the default python by:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

However, then, when I try to use pip install to install a library (say, boto), it is not available in python 2.7, but is available in 2.6.

Is "pip" somehow connected to 2.6? How do I change it so packages I install are installed for python 2.7?

Comment: `pip` is a package like any other in Python, so yes, the installed `pip` may be connected to 2.6. You'll have to install a new instance of `pip` in 2.7

Comment: How do I do that? How do I make sure this is the version of pip used from now on?

Comment: This is probably a good start: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html Then, make sure it is first on your PATH... or remove the old one...

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I had to install easy_install such that it uses python 2.7 and then use that easyinstall to install pip.

```
wget --no-check-certificate http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.35.tar.gz
tar xf distribute-0.6.35.tar.gz
cd distribute-0.6.35
sudo python2.7 setup.py install
sudo easy_install-2.7 pip
cd $current_dir
```